# Decode Product Customization on frontend and on backend (and emails)

Tags: php, json, smarty, prestashop

I've got a prestashop setup that has a small 'customization form' that currently saves the information to the products default customization text input. I did this to save time on having to write a complete custom module to add additional customization form fields and such.

Currently all the inputs are serialized (json) and entered as a long string into the text input like this:

```
Client Customization: %5B%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22trophy%5B1%5D%5Bline1%5D%22%2C%22engraving%22%3A%22Test%20Trophy%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22trophy%5B1%5D%5Bline2%5D%22%2C%22engraving%22%3A%22test%20trophy%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22trophy%5B1%5D%5Bline3%5D%22%2C%22engraving%22%3A%221111111%22%7D%5D%5D
```

On the front end - when the customized data is displayed I can use PHP to decode & display it appropriately.

Is there a way where I can change that globally somewhere so I don't have to try and find every place where it might display and add that PHP code?

I'm running into the issue that I can't seem to find where to add the PHP code to 'decode' that string for the emails that are being sent out - so the long ugly string is being seen instead of the nice few lines of customization the user entered.

Any thoughts on how to handle this? Is there a spot where I can globally assign the decoded string to the products customization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either try the PaymentModule class to decode the string just before the emails are sent, or Product's method called "getAllCustomizedDatas" for a more "global" approach.
And then test a lot, of course :)

Here's a quick draft of the second approach:

```
<?php
class Product extends ProductCore
{
    public static function getAllCustomizedDatas($id_cart, $id_lang = null, $only_in_cart = true, $id_shop = null)
    {
        $datas = parent::getAllCustomizedDatas($id_cart, $id_lang, $only_in_cart, $id_shop);

        /*
         * Iterate over $datas, you're looking for
         * [id_product][id_product_attribute][id_address_delivery][id_customization][datas]
         * Datas will contain an array of fields broken by their type. You can then decode
         * the ones that need to be decoded and return the result:
         */

        return $datas;
    }
}
```

Comment: I can just add an override for the Product class with just the 'getAllCustomizedDatas' method in it, right?

Comment: Yeah, you should be able to do that. See the edited answer